# Apply texture to mesh that has been extruded

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm super new to blender. I'm trying to build a room and I am trying to apply a texture to one of the walls. I had to extrude this wall to get it to the right size, so there's a few edges/faces that make up the entire shape. If I try to apply a texture, one face is textured differently than the rest of the faces.
[image]

If you see here, I have the entire plane selected, but the UV editor on the left only slected a portion of the texture. I have no idea why, so that's why I'm asking you guys how to fix this.
[image]

So you can see here that the bottom of the wall looks different from the rest of the wall. Can anyone here help a noob out?

Comment: If you make a change to your mesh you will need to UV Unwrap it again.

Comment: That's what I tried doing, even with the whole mesh selected, but for some reason the result was still the same

Comment: In Object Mode try Applying the Scale CTRL + "A" > Scale. Also, you could use the Project From View method of UV Unwrapping since it's flat. Just make sure your looking at it straight on.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a change to your mesh you will need to UV Unwrap it again.

In Object Mode Apply the Scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*.

Also, you could use the *Project From View* method of UV Unwrapping since it's flat. Just make sure your looking at it straight on.

**A quick tip on Modeling the wall**: Unless you plan on extruding "out" geometry your mesh would be much "cleaner" if, in Edit Mode,  you just selected the bottom two vertices (or top two) and pressed <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to grab them and move the only on the Z Axis. Then your left with a simple rectangle. If you Extrude the mesh down you are creating extra vertices and in complicated models that will increase render times unnecessarily.